# How to remove default fields a content entity

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8, drupal-entities

I was under the impression that by removing fields from `public static function baseFieldDefinitions` that they would not be required anymore during trying to save the entity. My function now only contains the following:

```
$fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
  ->setLabel(t('ID'))
  ->setDescription(t('The ID of the Content entity.'))
  ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

$fields['name'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
  ->setLabel(t('Name'))
  ->setDescription(t('The name of the Content entity.'))
  ->setSettings(array(
    'max_length' => 50,
    'text_processing' => 0,
  ))
  ->setDefaultValue('')
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'string',
    'weight' => -4,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'string_textfield',
    'weight' => -4,
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

However, when I try to add my entity it returns the following exception: `Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Field changed is unknown." at /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php line 474`

This is my first attempt at making a content entity so may be being done wrong.